# Reintegrating Gradle-ized project to exisiting Git

Tags: git, gradle, libgdx

I've re-setup my existing libGDX/android project to use gradle. This has involved a lot of project structure changes but very little code change. I've done all of this outside of Git. I would like to get this back into the master branch.

What is the best way to import and reintegrate this into the existing Git?

Edit: I have a brand new project outside of my working directory which I need to get back into the project. Merging does make sense to me since it isn't in Git and I just want it to replace the current head.

Comment: Remove everything except the .git directory from the directory containing the existing, git-versioned sources. Paste the new, modified sources inside this now empty directory, then add and commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `git add` all the files, until `git status` tells you that you have no untracked modifications, then `git commit`. Git will figure out what needs to be done.